# Проверить элементы в в списке кортежей на четность

Tags: python, list, кортежи

```
ListWithCortege = [(2, 4, 2, 1, 0), (4, 2, 1, 0), (1, 1, 0), (4, 1), (1, 4, 1),(1,)]

result = []
for cort in ListWithCortege:
    result.append(list(zip(cort, cort[1:])))
for i in result:
    print(i)
```

**Вывод:**

```
[(2, 4), (4, 2), (2, 1), (1, 0)]
[(4, 2), (2, 1), (1, 0)]
[(1, 1), (1, 0)]
[(4, 1)]
[(1, 4), (4, 1)]
[]
```

Как сюда ввернуть проверку типа: если количество элементов в элементе списка кортежей = 1, то добавить `99999`. Чтобы элемент `(1,)` стал `(1,99999)`.

***Вывод должен быть:***

```
[(2, 4), (4, 2), (2, 1), (1, 0)]
[(4, 2), (2, 1), (1, 0)]
[(1, 1), (1, 0)]
[(4, 1)]
[(1, 4), (4, 1)]
[(1,99999)]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

или так:

```
ListWithCortege = [(2, 4, 2, 1, 0), (4, 2, 1, 0), (1, 1, 0), (4, 1), (1, 4, 1),(1,)]

result = []
for cort in ListWithCortege:
    result.append(list(zip(cort, cort[1:] or (99999,))))
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
for i in result:
    print(i)
'''
[(2, 4), (4, 2), (2, 1), (1, 0)]
[(4, 2), (2, 1), (1, 0)]
[(1, 1), (1, 0)]
[(4, 1)]
[(1, 4), (4, 1)]
[(1, 99999)]
```

Comment: О, так короче, да. И без лишних преобразований.

Answer (score 1):

Например, так:

```py
result.append(list(zip(cort, list(cort[1:]) + [99999] * (len(cort) == 1))))
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```